# Get term by slug in Gutenberg

Tags: categories, javascript, taxonomy, block-editor

In Gutenberg, one can use the `getEntityRecord` selector to get the data of a term of a specific taxonomy by its term id:

```
// Get the category term with term id = 25
const term = useSelect( ( select ) =>
    select('core').getEntityRecord( 'taxonomy', 'category', 25 )
);
```

My question is, is there a way to get the data of a specific term by using the term slug instead of the term id? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one could search for a given term slug with `getEntityRecords`:

```
select('core').getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'category', { slug : 'my-slug' } )
```

by skimming through the endpoint reference that supports the `slug` query parameter.